# Autonumber for document numbering request list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, autonumber

We have a scenario where a user requests an "autonumber" for documents.

There is a field where they select the "document type" when adding a new item to the list, which is a lookup field (doc_type) held in another list call "Document_Types_Lookup".

The user could select one of up to 15 different document types when requesting a new item, and the autonumber should stay in sync with the document types...so there is no loss in the next available number for that particular document type.  This is why I can't simply use the ID column and append that to the "doc_type" field in a workflow.

Let's say we have the following autonumbers already in the list:
•DEMO-MATH-001
•DEMO-MATH-002
•DEMO-ENG-001
•DEMO-ENG-002
•DEMO-SCI-001

If a user submits a request for a MATH document, the number they should get to use is DEMO-MATH-003.

If a user submits a request for a SCI document, the number they should get to use is DEMO-SCI-002.

I have already used the autonumber in a workflow simply putting the ID column on the end, but this won't stay in sync with the particular doc type.

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use custom document ID service in order to achieve this. Here is a good example:
http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-sharepoint-server-2010-creating-a-custom-document-id-provider

Basically Document ID Service feature is available out of the box and provides you XXXX-YY-ZZ kind of auto number in document where you can configure XXXX from site collection administrator actions, but YY and ZZ are auto generated.

Let me know if you need more help